# ViewWillAppear Not called in tabbar items view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have structure:

*- TabBarViewController (Root)

*-- NavigationViewController

*---- ChatViewController

*-- NavigationViewController

*---- MenuViewController

and while I'm switching tabbar items, viewWillAppear in (Chat, Menu) called only once, but in NavigationVC called every times i switch.

Is it possible to call automatically viewWillAppeare in Chat and Menu ViewControllers while switching items?

super.viewWillAppear is inside method.

my code looks like:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let v1 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController")
    let v2 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController")
    viewControllers = [v1,v2]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(self,#function)
    }
}

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(self,#function)
    }
}
```

It works on clear new project but on old ( where im working, and i have loot of funcionality, doesn't work)

StoryboardId is linked to NavigationViewController in `Storyboard`

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Post your code related to tabbarController

Answer (score 1):

I found issue: 
In `extension UINavigationController` i have method

```
    open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if !UserDefaults.standard.isUserPresented {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = .rgbColor(red: 43, green: 43, blue: 43, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = .rgbColor(red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
```

and this block viewWillAppear in child view controllers in NavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about adding viewcontroller to tabbarcontroller and navigation controller . I have created everything in storyboard . View will appear in view controller are :

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("Menu View will appear")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("Chat View will appear")
    }
```

Am able to get below output when i switch :

```
Menu View will appear
Chat View will appear
Menu View will appear
Chat View will appear
```